# Using an Excel file to stock changing parameters for a SAS program

Tags: excel, parameters, sas

I have a SAS program which simulates the tax system of a country, with lines like:

```
if         0<income<bound1      then
    tax = rate1 * income;
else if    bound1<income<bound2 then
    tax = rate2 * income;
```

and so on...

My concern is that I want to use this program for different years, and that all the parameters change over time, at least because of inflation, but also fiscal changes.
Therefore, I would like all the parameters like bound_1, rate_1 and so on, to be in an Excel file that I can modify for each year more easily than a SAS program.

Searching for that, I only find results on how to read datasets from Excel or how to export certain procedures in Excel, which is not what I want.

To be more precise, I have an Excel file, something like "X:/TaxSystem.xls", and I would like to do something like

```
if 0<income<"cellE1" then
    tax = "cellF1" * income;
else if    "cellE1"<income<"cellE1" then
    tax = "cellF2" * income;
```

So that I would only change my cells, which would be more sustainable and prevent for forgetting to change just one value

Comment: Your params in Excel are organised in some way, probably like a table? If so, you need to get them into SAS. You can use PROC IMPORT or Libref engine to get it in as a SAS dataset. Once you have it in, you can get the parameters you need to do the modelling.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project and after trying a few different approaches, the one that I settled on as seeming least prone to unpleasant surprises went like this:

- Set up your workbook so that the relevant Excel table is isolated on one sheet;
- Create a VBA macro that exports that sheet to new workbook and saves it as
  .csv or .txt, and closes it;
- Program SAS to import the .csv or .txt file you created.
- If desired, you can also add code to SAS to delete the .csv or .txt file once it's imported.

I like this approach because it forces the process though a clean and understandable flat-file bottleneck.  This limits the ways Excel can ruin your day.

If you want to really integrate it, you can set up your VBA macro to also execute the SAS program so the end user only has to make one click to set the whole thing off.